# PHPPresentation and .pptx using php

Tags: php, xml, powerpoint

How can I include/load a pptx file (/wwwroot/PHPPresentation/file.pptx) in my index.php so it could be opened automatically as a diashow? I have tried using PHPPresentation but his library just allows to create a new objPHPPresentation(properties and etc...) or to add a currentSlide but not an external slide from i.e. file.pptx 
I just started with this last week but still got no ideas. I also tried to unzip first file.pptx so I could handle with xml extensions and at this point I'm afraid to ask if it was a good idea seeing that I'm not really good at xml but if it's possible in that way I'll be much appreciated for any help/advices.

Comment: You wish display the pptx file in your index.php ?

Comment: Hi Progi1984, indeed and by loading the index.php the presentation starts. Thks for your reply.

Comment: Or can I also add an existing pptx to a new phppresentation?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PHPPresentation doesn't have any Writer HTML. So you can't display it in a browser.

An issue has been opened : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/issues/221